# Xcode execute “Test” from command line?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I would like to build my iOS project (cocoapods) from command line, so I will be able to build it on jenkins. First trigger all unit tests after every commit. On Xcode it is easy, `Product -> Test`. Can I somehow check what command is executed when I click on it?

I found this: [developer.apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/08-automation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH7-SW1)

Comment: I will recommend you to check this article  https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/running-tests-from-the-terminal/

Comment: @bazyl87 when I click in XCode, all tests are running, from in command line see the error: `xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "MySDKCore" does not contain a scheme named "MySDKCore". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.` I would like to check command with XCode triggers when press the button, can I check it in the logs or any views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe someone in the future will look for this, so this is how I solved it:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace' -scheme 'SchemaTests' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=12.1'
```